# Could not import/No module named Django Error with Apache

Tags: django, apache

I had a small proof of concept set up on a development server on a local machine.  I'm now trying to move it over to django on a production server, which I'm using webfaction for.  However, now that I'm switched over to apache from the built in django server I get the following:

```
ViewDoesNotExist: Could not import orgDisplay.views. Error was: No module named orgDisplay.views
```

But when check my orgDisplay apps folder there is a view.py in it.  What am I doing wrong?  I've tried adding the following to my settings.py by suggestion of the django IRC room.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"/home/user/webapps/django_project/myproject/orgDisplay")
```

which is the path to my app.

any ideas on how to even begin to trouble shoot this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're using `mod_wsgi` (which is recommended by Django authors), not `mod_python`. This is the way you should use your sys.path:

django.wsgi:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(r"/home/user/webapps/django_project/myproject/")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "settings"

sys.stdout = sys.stderr # Prevent crashes upon print

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
urlpatterns = (
   ("", include("orgDisplay.urls")),
   # ...
)
```

orgDisplay/urls.py:

```
import views

urlpatterns = ( 
    (r'^some_view/$', views.some_view), # It is actually orgDisplay.views.some_view
    # many more records ...
)
```

It is a bad idea to add project dir itself to path since you're be getting name conflicts between multiple projects.

Comment: I believe if I added import orgDisplay.views that would probably fix it.  So do I add that to my urls.py file?  It seems odd I'd have to go mucking around in my settings like that.

Comment: Updated my answer with full urlconf setup

Answer (score 3):

I think you're appending the wrong directory to `sys.path`. I think Python is looking in the `.../myproject/orgDisplay` folder for the `orgDisplay` package. Try removing the `orgDisplay` from your string, like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"/home/user/webapps/django_project/myproject")
```

The other option would be to simply add `myproject` (or whatever your project is actually called) in the import statement.

```
# instead of "from orgDisplay import views"
from myproject.orgDisplay import views
```

Also, make sure to restart Apache after every edit.

Comment: I don't see the difference between your append statement and mine.

Also, where would I add the import statement.  In my urls.py file?  That is where I'm calling this from.

Comment: i added from myproject.orgDisplay import views to my urls.py file and still no luck.

Comment: My mistake. I copied your code directly and forgot to make the changes. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

looking at manage.py, it does it like so:

```
import sys

from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
from django.core.management import setup_environ


# setup the environment before we start accessing things in the settings.
setup_environ(settings_mod)

sys.path.insert(0, join(PINAX_ROOT, "apps"))
sys.path.insert(0, join(PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided your WSGI file is in your project directory, a slightly more flexible way is this:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

This will enable you to change your project location later without having to modify your WSGI file.